# Help me with making macOS USB on Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, usb

The macOS partition in my Mac is corrupted and now all I have is a Ubuntu. I'm trying to make a Mac OS USB disk from Linux and I'm stuck without much options. I read [here](https://www.winytips.com/download-macos-dmg-full-offline-installer/) that if download DMG files for Mac you can make macOS USB in Windows. Is there any tool/method for this on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

The software to convert a DMG to an IMG is `dmg2img` and an IMG is basically an ISO:

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install dmg2img
```

Converting to IMG:

```
dmg2img {file}.dmg
```

- you will end up with {file}.img

Burn it to an unmounted USB:

```
sudo umount /dev/sd{Y} 
sudo dd bs=4M if={file}.img of=/dev/sd{X}
```

- replace {file} to your filename
- replace {Y} to the letter of your USB pendrive
- `df -h` will list the pendrive when it is mounted so you can find {Y} there.